# Why does getting a xml dataset table return all values?

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset

[image]
Currently, I have this Datagridview displaying some XML data, the data is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<survey>
  <floor location="Drill Floor">
    <sign location ="1" ref="OFS-FE01" size="180x180"  Material="RPP" Quantity="2" Backingboard="No"  />
  </floor>
  <floor location="Top Deck">
    <sign location ="2" ref="OFS-FE07" size="180x180"  Material="RPP" Quantity="2" Backingboard="Yes"  />
  </floor>
  </survey>
```

This is where I'm stuck as there are multiple floors and I need a way to display only a chosen floor location.

```
    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXml(@"basicStorage.sws", XmlReadMode.Auto);
        datagridview.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[1].DataSet.Tables[1];
    }
```

Above is how im loading the datagridview, It works but it gets all the places, while I only want to get it from a certain floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pre-process the XML file to remove the data which you don't want to show in the data grid view (I'm assuming `basicStorage.sws` is an xml file)

For example:

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument storedData = XDocument.Load(@"basicStorage.sws");

    // the floor that you want to keep
    string selectedFloor = "Drill Floor";

    // remove everything that isn't the floor we want to keep
    storedData
        .Descendants("floor")
        .Where(a => a.Attribute("location").Value != selectedFloor)
        .Remove();

    // now use the remaining xml to populate the dataset
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.ReadXml(storedData.CreateReader());
    datagridview.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[1].DataSet.Tables[1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this was out of the office for a few days so only just saw this.